# How to avoid function call in js in large loops?

Tags: javascript

I have double for loop in my code.It usually runs `more than 40,000 times`.In the for loop,there are some functions to do something.
The function call usually cost 0.002s ,It will cost more than 100s in total, so I think if I use `inline function` just like `C++`.The cost will be avoid.
But how can I define an `inline function` like`C++ line function`? Simply replace the code is not nice and hard to implement.

Comment: Are you sure about those numbers? I don't believe a Javascript function call costs 2ms.

Comment: Doing such heavy lifting in JS code running in a browser may not be a great design. You should change the design to avoid such huge number of loops in JS code. Community may be able to help if you post the code or give more information about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I am not use js in browser but in Flash.

Comment: 40,000 X 0.002 would equate to 80 seconds, not more than 100... if you don't expect 80K unique results, you can often cache the function's argument/result set using a js object...

Comment: I finally found that API is slowly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's your case, but sometimes it is handy to use tool called **cpp2js**. It allows you to create inline C++ functions inside your JavaScript code. Those C++ code is executed on server. Here you can find documentation: http://www.speqmath.com/tutorials/cpp2js/index.html.